# How can I wrap my mean separation labels so that they are centered above each bar (in a ggplot2 graph)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that I am working with (fabricated to protect confidentiality), and I need to construct a bar graph to represent differences in the data. The problem is that my mean separation letters are long and often times run into the other bars. How can I wrap them so that they are above their correct bars and do not interfere with the others?

Here is my dataset and code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

## Data to work with
data <- data.frame("trt" = c('t1',
                             't1',
                             't1',
                             't1',
                             't2',
                             't2',
                             't2',
                             't2',
                             't3',
                             't3',
                             't3',
                             't3',
                             't4',
                             't4',
                             't4',
                             't4'),
                   "splt" = c(1,
                              2,
                              3,
                              4,
                              1,
                              2,
                              3,
                              4,
                              1,
                              2,
                              3,
                              4,
                              1,
                              2,
                              3,
                              4),
                   "response"=c(82,
                                62,
                                17,
                                93,
                                55,
                                99,
                                42,
                                67,
                                56,
                                8,
                                62,
                                69,
                                38,
                                80,
                                86,
                                26),
                   standard_error=c(2,
                                    5,
                                    3,
                                    3,
                                    1,
                                    4,
                                    4,
                                    6,
                                    4,
                                    4,
                                    1,
                                    5,
                                    5,
                                    5,
                                    6,
                                    4),
                   hsd=c('abcdef',
                         'abcdef',
                         'abcdefg',
                         'abcdefg',
                         'abcdefgh',
                         'abcdefgh',
                         'abcdefgh',
                         'abcdefgh',
                         'abcdefgh',
                         'abcdefgh',
                         'abcdefgh',
                         'abcdefgh',
                         'abcdefgh',
                         'abcdefgh',
                         'abcdefgh',
                         'abcdefgh'))

# Change to factor
data$splt <- as.factor(data$splt)

ggplot(data, aes(fill = splt, x = trt, y = response))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.6, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), col = "black")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = response, ymax = response + standard_error), 
                width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend("Splt"))+
  xlab("Treatment")+
  ylab('Response')+
  ggtitle("Title",
          subtitle = "Subtitle")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 15),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 11),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.3, 'cm'))+
  geom_text(aes(label = str_wrap(hsd, width = 10), y = response + standard_error, group = splt), vjust = -0.9, 
            size = 4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8))+
  ylim(0, 110)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10))
```

As can be seen in the image below, there is a lot of overlap, but I need to fix this. I tried using the `geom_text(aes(label = str_wrap(hsd, width = 10)` to do this, but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `str_wrap` would be great, but unfortunately it only works on words (ie, with whitespace - "abc defg", not "abcdefg"). You can create a little helper function that will replace that:

```
mystrfun <- function(string, dist = 3){
  left <- substr(string, 1, dist)
  right <- substr(string, dist+1, nchar(string))
  paste0(left, "\n", right)
}
```

Where `dist` is the character length you want to separate on.

Then replacing `str_wrap` in your original code with `mystrfun`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(fill = splt, x = trt, y = response))+
  ...+
  geom_text(aes(label = mystrfun(hsd), y = response + standard_error, group = splt), vjust = -0.9, 
            size = 4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8))+
  ylim(0, 110) +
...
```

Will yield:

[image]